# How does Hive works regular expression with < and > symbols?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

This is siva Ramanjaneyulu, I am working on hive. I have got the following problem with hive

sample.log: `<ABC>`

```
CREATE TABLE sample4(  num1 STRING ) ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH
SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = "<.*>", "output.format.string" =
"%1$s" ) STORED AS TEXTFILE; 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "../hive-0.9.0/sample.log" INTO TABLE sample4; 

select * from sample4;

NULL
```

Expected output: ABC

Why does this `.RegexSerDe` not work on regular exprssion `<.*>`?

how it is possible to remove < and > symbels using regular expression , can u please provide solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> hive> CREATE TABLE s(num1 STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH
>   SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = "(<.*>)", 
>   "output.format.string" = "%1$s" ) STORED AS TEXTFILE;

Mind the `parentheses` around regex.

Comment: ok, thank u Tariq, but i am expecting output ABC not <ABC>, can u please provide solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NULL value because you didn't include the parentheses in the regex definition.  If you don't want the angle brackets to be included in the output you need to put them outside the parentheses.  The stuff inside the parenthesis is what will be returned as the output.

```
CREATE TABLE sample4 (num1 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "<(.*)>"
  , "output.format.string" = '%1$s'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```